# Generate a function from a graph

Tags: graphing-functions

I want to generate a simulator for behavior that is displayed via charts.

The end result will be a behavior that follows some formula like

$$f(x) = \sin(x)$$

which will output a sine behavior.

However, I want to create my own “handmade” graphs to simulate different scenarios. Is there a tool online where I can draw a graph and it will output its formula (in whatever complexity or approximation)?

Answer (score 3):

Yes and no.

There are tools which allow you to design so-called free-form curves obtained by (polynomial or piecewise polynomial) interpolation or by approximation. These will be defined on a finite domain.

https://www.ibiblio.org/e-notes/Splines/Intro.htm

But if you want special features like vertical tangents, cornerpoints, periodicity, specific asymptotic behavior$\ldots$ polynomials won’t suffice.

For a better answer, you need to be more specific.